# Can we use <i> inside heading tags

Tags: html

Is it appropriate to use `<i>` tag within any of the heading tags?

html:

```
<div class="">      
   <h5>Hello <i>HI</i> </h5>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a question of whether or not you need it to be in italics. If yes then go for it, if no, then don't. If you are going to use it multiple times, then have it in you CSS

Comment: An i in a heading is no different from an i in a paragraph or anywhere else. Refer to the spec for how the i element should be used: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element

Comment: The question is, though, what is your intention? Depending on the effect you want to convey, there may be elements more suited for the job. `<em>`, `<cite>` and `<var>` spring to mind immediately, but there are more...

Answer (score 0):

Yes its appropriate, You can use i tag inside the other html tags. Mainly i tag used for italics. You  can achieve the same result by using CSS also.
for more information about i tag please visit http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_i.asp

Answer (score -1):

Yes, definitely, You can use `<i>` tag inside any HTML tags. Nowadays it is used to display vector icons like font-awesome icons, glyphicons and many more.

Comment: In case you're wondering about the downvote, it's probably because of your blanket "any HTML tags". That's simply not true. You can't use `<i>` inside `<colgroup>`, `<col>`, `<head>`, `<title>`, `<script>` or as a direct child of `<table>`, `<tbody>`, `<tr>`, `<ul>` etc.